# Restrict layer issue in EAGLE using C1206F334K1RACTU capacitor

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, surface-mount

I've been trying to google this problem and find solutions in this forum as well, however, as I am still new to EAGLE and posting in this forum I'd appreciate any advice.

I have been trying to connect a trace to the capacitor shown below. However, there is a **restrict** area all around it. The restrict area is doing what it should be: keeping the copper traces out and if I do connect, DRC will show an error. However, if the footprint is like this then how should the copper trace be connected to the terminals of this component?

Some things to note: I did not make this component's footprint but took it from ultralibrarian, link to the component: https://app.ultralibrarian.com/details/c534c2dd-1072-11e9-ab3a-0a3560a4cccc/Kemet/C1206F334K1RACTU?uid=12793254

[image]

Comment: Edit the part and remove that area. Makes no sense to have it there.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow this.

Comment: Just use a standart 1206 cap footprint that's already in the Eagle library, if there's no reason not to.

Comment: Just general suggestion, double check each footprint you didnt create yourself. just recently I used footprint from default library (for SMD transistor) which didnt have solder stop mask... Fortunately I caught it in manufacturers PCB viewer.

Answer (score 1):

The box should be on the Keepout layer, not the Restrict layer.

- The Keepout layer is intended to prevent other components being placed there. If Keepout shapes from different components overlap, Eagle will give a DRC error.
- The Restrict layer is to stop copper being placed there. If copper overlaps a restrict, Eagle will give a DRC error - but the pads are copper, so is the trace that connects them, so it makes no sense to use it where it is.

But for passive components in standard packages such as 1206, etc, Eagle has a library for that - there is the RCL library.